# cakephp authentication limit

Tags: authentication, scope

For some reasons scope condition is not working and i cant figure out why so need your help

my AppController

```
public $components = array(
    'Acl',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email'),
                'scope' => array('User.is_active' => 1)
            )
        )
    ),
    'Session'
);
```

User can login whatever is he active or not

Also tried

```
array('User.is_active' => '1')
array('User.is_active' => true)
array('User.is_active' => 'true')
```

Comment: This question cannot be reproduced, and should be closed

Answer (score 0):

damn....
After qustion tried couple more times and it worked hmmmmm... someone is messing with me

btw it is working with

`array('User.is_active' => '1')`